# Encoding of a string in c#

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, encoding

I was translating some C++ code to C# and I saw the below function

```
myMultiByteToWideChar( encryptedBufUnicode, (char*)encryptedBuf, sizeof(encryptedBufUnicode) );
```

This basically converts the char array to unicode.

In C#, aren't strings and char arrays already unicode? Or do we need to make it unicode using a system.text function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# strings and characters are UTF-16.

If you have an array of bytes, you can use the `Encoding` class to read it as a string using a correct encoding.